# NestJS y TypeORM: InjectRepository undefined

Tags: typescript

Tengo un problema en un servicio que estoy desarrollando con nestjs y TypeORM

El sistema corre con docker, todo funciona bien en mi pc, pero cuando lo corro en cualquier otro lado deja de funcionar.

El error dice :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`

indicando que el repository que injecto no esta definido

BasicRepository:

```
export abstract class BasicRepository<Entity> {

  constructor(protected readonly repository: Repository<Entity>,
protected readonly request: Request) {
     console.log("basicRepo", this.repository.metadata.givenTableName) 
  }
}
```

UserRepository:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { BasicRepository } from './basic.repository';
import { UserEntity } from '../../shared/entities/user.entity';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class UserRepository extends BasicRepository<UserEntity> {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity) public readonly repository: Repository<UserEntity>,
    @Inject(REQUEST) public readonly request: Request,
  ) {
    super(repository, request);
  }
}
```

TapRepository:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository, FindManyOptions, getConnection, getManager } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { BasicRepository } from './basic.repository';
import { TapEntity} from '../../shared/entities/tap.entity';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class TapRepository extends BasicRepository<TapEntity> {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TapEntity) public readonly repository: Repository<TapEntity>,
    @Inject(REQUEST) public readonly request: Request,
  ) {
    super(repository, request);
  }
}
```

Lo raro(aparte de que en mi computadora no me sale este error) es que en este caso UserRepository no me da error, pero si los demas.

Solo funciona en mi pc, por lo general corro el sistema usando kubernetes, falla cuando quiero correrlo en GKE(google) o EKS(amazon).

Otra cosa que pasa es que el mensaje 'basicRepo' que imprime el nombre de la tabla del repositorio solo se imprime con la clase UserRepository.